# Converting C# to VB - Private String Statement

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, string

I have been given some C# code which defined some Private String but I am not sure what it is doing honestly and need to convert into VB for my Project but wandered if someone might take a moment to explain and possible provide a conversion?

```
private string GetChecksum(StringBuilder buf)
           {
        // calculate checksum of message
        uint sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += (char)buf[i];
               }
         return string.Format("{0:X04}", sum);
    }
```

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Is it the _syntax_ or the _procedure_ that you don't understand?  All it's doing is adding up the ASCII values of each character in the string, with the end result modulo-65536 since there is no overflow checking.

Answer (score 1):

The part with `private string ...` is the method declaration. C#'s

> *Accessibility* *ReturnType* *MethodName*(*Type* *paramName*)

translates to

> *Accessibility* `Function` *MethodName*(*paramName* `As` *Type*) `As` *ReturnType*

Comment: Thanks bu was more interested in the content of the Function:

        uint sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += (char)buf[i];
               }
         return string.Format("{0:X04}", sum);

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function GetChecksum(buf As StringBuilder) As String
    'calculate checksum of message
    Dim sum As UInteger = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To buf.Length - 1
        sum += CChar(buf(i))
    Next
    Return String.Format("{0:X04}", sum)
End Function
```

Comment: I think the `CChar` is redundant as `buf(i)` is already a Char.

Comment: In addition, this will not compile with `Option Strict On` as the + operator cannot be applied to a Char and UInteger.

Answer (score 0):

What the function does is adds up the ASCII values of each character in the string (stored in a 2-byte `char` without overflow checking) and return the result as a string - the 4-character hexadecimal representation of the 2-byte result.

A checksum is used to detect data errors; if two strings yield different checksums then they cannot be equal.  Two strings that give the same checksum, however, are non necessarily equal, so it cannot be used to verify equality.